# Android Job Scheduler

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I was learning about `JobScheduler` with a Tutorial from 2015, and when I was creating a class of this service,it complains asking me to put the annotation `@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)`, which means, doesn't work for old versions? And if it is, `GCMNetworkManager` would be the one ?

Answer (score 0):

> which means, doesn't work for old versions?

Yes annotation specifies that API wont work under `LOLLIPOP` version

> And if it is, GCMNetworkManager would be the one ?

Alternatives to JobScheduler are

- AlarmManager
- GCMNetworkManager
- SyncAdapter

You should choose one that suits your need with minimal device resource utilisation.

Note: Avoid using services that run perpetually or perform periodic work, since they continue to use device resources even when they are not performing useful tasks.